# Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1 (Not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

.js file including an array of Strings which suppose to generate random words when one of the buttons click on the HTML page but for some reason it has a problem of scoping variables (as much as I've understood in other threads) but I don't know how to set it straight..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBaTD.png)

```js
var interval;
var randomNum;

function newSubject(str) {
 
 clearInterval(interval);
 randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*(str.length));
 interval = setInterval(document.getElementById('generator').innerHTML = str[randomNum],1000);
 
}

**var adjectives** = [
'מסוגל',
'מקסים',
'הרפתקני',
'חומצי',
'פעיל',
'מפחד',
'מזדקן',
'אגרסיבי',
'נעים',
'ערמומי',
'מדאיג',
'ערני',
'חי',
'מדהים',
'משועשע',
'עתיק',
'מתבייש',
'מושך',
'ממוצע',
'נורא',
];

var food = [
'אוכל',
'קובנה',
'קוסקוס',
'המבורגר',
'לחם',
'גבינה',
'טבעוני',
'צמחוני',
];

var nature = [
'עץ',
'שדה',
'דשא',
'רוח',
'אדמה',
'מים',
'אש',
];

var space = [
'כדור הארץ',
'אטמוספרה',
'ירח',
'כוכבים',
'חללית',
'חלל חיצון',
'חייזר',
'ונוס',
'שמש',
];

var tech = [
'מכונה',
'בינארי',
'אפס',
'אחד',
'מחשב',
'כוח עיבוד',
];
When buttons
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Connection Freestyler</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hebrew Freestyle Generator" />
    <meta name="author" content="Connection">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="words.js"></script>
 
    </head>
 
<body>
 <div class="main"> 
  <div class="refresh" onclick="">
  Refresh Every 5 Secs
  </div>
  
  <div class="generator" id="generator">
  Generator "Select Subject"
  </div>
  
  <div class="subjects">
  
   **<button class="adjectives" id="adjectives" onclick="newSubject(adjectives)">**
   Adjectives
   </button>
  
   <button class="food" id="food" onclick="newSubject(food)"> 
   Food
   </button>
   
   <button class="nature" id="nature" onclick="newSubject(nature)">
   Nature
   </button>
   
   <button class="space" id="space" onclick="newSubject(space)">
   Space
   </button>
   
   <button class="tech" onclick="newSubject(tech)">
   Tech
   </button>
  </div> 
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I've also tried to put every variable in any scope combination possible but it stick to the same error everytime.

Comment: There's no underscore in your code, so how would we know what the problem is?

Comment: Ohh my bad , Uncaught ReferenceError: משועשע is not defined
  at <anonymous>:1:1
There is also a picture link (I'm new to making a post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` accept function as parameter. use

```
interval = setInterval(() => document.getElementById('generator').innerHTML = str[randomNum],1000);
```

and assuming you mean to make a new random every second, use

```
document.getElementById('generator').innerHTML = str[randomNum];
interval = setInterval(() => newSubject(str),1000);
```

snipped:

```js
var interval;
var randomNum;

function newSubject(str) {
 
 clearInterval(interval);
 randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*(str.length));
  document.getElementById('generator').innerHTML = str[randomNum];
 interval = setInterval(() => newSubject(str),1000);
 
}

var adjectives = [
'מסוגל',
'מקסים',
'הרפתקני',
'חומצי',
'פעיל',
'מפחד',
'מזדקן',
'אגרסיבי',
'נעים',
'ערמומי',
'מדאיג',
'ערני',
'חי',
'מדהים',
'משועשע',
'עתיק',
'מתבייש',
'מושך',
'ממוצע',
'נורא',
];

var food = [
'אוכל',
'קובנה',
'קוסקוס',
'המבורגר',
'לחם',
'גבינה',
'טבעוני',
'צמחוני',
];

var nature = [
'עץ',
'שדה',
'דשא',
'רוח',
'אדמה',
'מים',
'אש',
];

var space = [
'כדור הארץ',
'אטמוספרה',
'ירח',
'כוכבים',
'חללית',
'חלל חיצון',
'חייזר',
'ונוס',
'שמש',
];

var tech = [
'מכונה',
'בינארי',
'אפס',
'אחד',
'מחשב',
'כוח עיבוד',
];
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="main"> 
  <div class="refresh" onclick="">
  Refresh Every 5 Secs
  </div>
  
  <div class="generator" id="generator">
  Generator "Select Subject"
  </div>
  
  <div class="subjects">
  
   **<button class="adjectives" id="adjectives" onclick="newSubject(adjectives)">**
   Adjectives
   </button>
  
   <button class="food" id="food" onclick="newSubject(food)"> 
   Food
   </button>
   
   <button class="nature" id="nature" onclick="newSubject(nature)">
   Nature
   </button>
   
   <button class="space" id="space" onclick="newSubject(space)">
   Space
   </button>
   
   <button class="tech" onclick="newSubject(tech)">
   Tech
   </button>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Works like charm , Thank you sooo much for the help !